# Django Haystack custom form custom attribute returns no results

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-haystack

I have made my own SearchForm following instructions from [Django website](http://django-haystack.readthedocs.org/en/latest/views_and_forms.html), but for some reason if I add my own search field, it doesn't return any results, even when it should return results.

My search_indexes.py:

```
from haystack import indexes 
from my.app.models import MyModel

class MyIndexIndex(indexes.SearchIndex, indexes.Indexable):
    text = indexes.NgramField(document=True, use_template=True)    
    my_fieldname = indexes.CharField(model_attr='my_fieldname')

    def get_model(self):
        return MyModel
```

My model:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    some_field1 = models.CharField(_('Some field 1'), max_length=255)
    some_field2 = models.CharField(_('Some field 2'), max_length=255)

    my_fieldname = models.CharField(_('My field name'), max_length=255)
```

My search form:

```
class MySearchForm(SearchForm):
    q = forms.CharField(label="Search", max_length=255, required=False)
    my_fieldname = forms.CharField(label="MySearchLabel", max_length=255, required=False)

    def search(self):
        sqs = super(MySearchForm, self).search()

        if self.is_valid() and self.cleaned_data['my_fieldname']:
            sqs = sqs.filter(my_fieldname=AutoQuery(self.cleaned_data['my_fieldname']))

        return sqs
```

My urls.py:

```
urlpatterns += patterns('haystack.views',
    url(r'^search/', SearchView(
        form_class=MySearchForm
    ), name='haystack_search'),
)
```

I have run manage.py rebuild_index, but it doesn't affect. My question is what I am doing wrong here, why I am not getting any results. If I try some queries with q parameters, results are returned normally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`super(MySearchForm, self).search()` performs an `auto_query()` with a default field name of `content`... As you haven't defined a field like this it will not return any results... Therefore I wouldn't do the `super` call, but replace with an implementation similar to the [original one](https://github.com/toastdriven/django-haystack/blob/master/haystack/forms.py#L44) - but pass a `fieldname` to [`auto_query`](https://github.com/toastdriven/django-haystack/blob/master/haystack/query.py#L434): `auto_query(querystring, fieldname='text')`.

Also make sure to have the template defined correctly if you are searching in it. (If you are chaining multiple `filter()` calls they will be combined usind *and*).

Also depending on the search engine you use it will probably offer you a frontend where you can check independently from haystack if the data is indexed properly...